# Android - GridView's onResume

Tags: android

I am developing Android apps,

once part of this apps is creating a GridView that contain some image (the image is loaded from URL),

then another activity that show the selected image in full screen will be appeared when one of image in GridView is onClick.

Problem:

When I enter the GridView activity, it takes some second to load all image in gridview normally.

Then I click one of image to enter the full screen activity and click back button to go back to GridView,

but, it takes some second to loading when go back to gridview, just like loading all image again.

I wonder why the gridview activity will loading for a few second when onResume?

For example, in Google Play, the full screen view of sample image in any apps can be back to previous view immediately.

Enclosed code:

GridView:

```
public class ManagePhoto extends Activity {

ImageAdapter ia;
GridView gridview;
InputStream inputStream;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String selectedImagePath;
TextView tvRunningMark;
boolean bRunning;
String[] purl;
Bitmap[] bm;
String the_string_response;
TouchImageView touch;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.photo_manage);

    //gv is Gobal Value
    final Gvalue gv = ((Gvalue) getApplicationContext());

    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gv_photo);
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new GridView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView adapterView, View view,int position, long id) {
            gv.setbm(bm[position]);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(adapterView.getContext(), FullScreenImage.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
        }
    });
    new GridTask().execute();
}

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return purl.length;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) { // if it's not recycled, initialize some
                                    // attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200,200));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        try {
            bm[position] = loadBitmap(purl[position]);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm[position]);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return imageView;
    }
}

class GridTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        gridview.setAdapter(ia);
        final LinearLayout llo_probar = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.llo_probar);
        llo_probar.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
        gridview.setVisibility(GridView.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {         
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {         
        getphoto();
        bm = new Bitmap[purl.length];
        ia = new ImageAdapter(ManagePhoto.this);
        return null;
    }

}

private Bitmap loadBitmap(String url) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FlushedInputStream(
            (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent()));
}

class FlushedInputStream extends FilterInputStream {
    public FlushedInputStream(final InputStream inputStream) {
        super(inputStream);
    }

    @Override
    public long skip(final long n) throws IOException {
        long totalBytesSkipped = 0L;

        while (totalBytesSkipped < n) {
            long bytesSkipped = in.skip(n - totalBytesSkipped);

            if (bytesSkipped == 0L) {
                int bytesRead = read();

                if (bytesRead < 0) { // we reached EOF
                    break;
                }

                bytesSkipped = 1;
            }

            totalBytesSkipped += bytesSkipped;
        }

        return totalBytesSkipped;
    }
}

public void getphoto(){
    final Gvalue gv = ((Gvalue) getApplicationContext());
    final TextView tv_fn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_fn);
    String result = "";
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sql",
            ("select * from personal_photo where member_id = " + gv.getuid())));

    InputStream is = null;
    // http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://" + gv.getserverIP()
                + "/android_getdata.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();

        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // parse json data
    try {
        List url = new ArrayList();
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            url.add(json_data.getString("save_location"));
        }
        int size = url.size();
        purl = new String[size];
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            purl[j] = (String) url.get(j);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
}

public void toast(String text) {
    Toast.makeText(ManagePhoto.this, text, 5).show();
}
}
```

Full screen:

```
public class FullScreenImage extends Activity {
TouchImageView touch;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    new ShowPhotoTask().execute();
}

class ShowPhotoTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        setContentView(touch);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        setContentView(R.layout.full_image);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        final Gvalue gv = ((Gvalue) getApplicationContext());
        touch = new TouchImageView(FullScreenImage.this);
        touch.setMaxZoom(4f); // change the max level of zoom, default is 3f
        touch.setImageBitmap(gv.getbm());
        return null;
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your `getView` code in your `ImageAdapter`, everytime you will  load the image from the internet again.

You should download the image to local, next time, when your set the image, you try to get it from local firstly.

As well you should put the get bitmap in the thread as you have putting the parse JSON in the thread.

Here is an [demo](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList), i think it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In your gridview onclick you are starting activity with startActivityForResults(intent,0); replace it with startActivity(intent);

also when you are finishing the FullScreenActivity just use finish();

might solve your problem

Comment: I just changes to.. startActivity(intent); and at finish() to onBackPressed() in FullScreenActivity, but not working.. Thanks for help

Comment: same, also need some second for loading in onBack

Answer (score 0):

It's so slow because you don't perform your operations with background threads, caching..
A **simple** and **better** solution could be a collection that contains all your bitmaps inserted by AsyncTasks that you'll execute to download the pictures.

There are better solutions but they are more difficult to implement.
For example you can consider the possibility to keep a thread pool that resolves your runnables represented by "download the http://jhon.doe.jpg" and then "show now on the UI thread".

Comment: Sorry, i am newbie in android develop. May you giving me some suggestion about that better solutions? Actually, do you having any idea about how 'Google Play' do it that i mention above?

Answer (score 0):

As you have written below function inside the getView() method:

```
 bm[position] = loadBitmap(purl[position]);
```

I would say you should implement code to **load Image Asynchronously**. In this logic, image is synced in your memory card once its downloading is done. So next time it will load directly from memory card instead of loading it from web again.

Here is a code example you can give a try: [**Android - Universal Image Loader**](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)